# Page numbering in word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, page-numbers

I have a word document with 20 pages. I have it numbered Page 1 of 20 ending numbering on page 15. The last 5 pages are not numbered. I want them not numbered.  My question is how do I end the numbering so it reads Page 1 of 15 not 1 of 20.  I don't want the last 5 pages included in the counting.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of page 15, insert a section break.
Go to the page numbering in the first section, i.e. the footer (or header). Hit the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> to show the codes. It should read something like

```
Page { Page } of { NUMPAGES }
```

Change that to

```
Page { Page } of { SECTIONPAGES }
```

and the second number will display the number of pages in the current section after you refresh the fields with F9 and toggle back field codes to normal display with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: If that answers your question, please mark the answer as described in the [Tour](http://superuser.com/tour)